# Запрос Select не воспринимает переменную из кода

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, строки, запрос

В интернете нашла кучу подсказок, как в запрос `insert` добавить определенные переменные из кода, но нашла лишь одно упоминание про вставку переменной, заданной ранее, в запрос `select`, который к тому же у меня не работает. Перепробовала уже миллион разных вариантов, только в цикле еще все ответы не перебирала (надеюсь, до этого не дойдет).

```
QSqlQuery qry1;
qry1.prepare("select max(Missiles_id) from Missiles");
qry1.exec();
qry1.next();
int missId=qry1.value(0).toInt();
qDebug()<<missId;

qry=new QSqlQuery;
qry->prepare("SELECT * FROM Missiles WHERE Missiles_id="+missId);
qry->exec();

model->setQuery(*qry);
ui->tableViewMissiles->setModel(model);
ui->tableViewMissiles->horizontalHeader()-> resizeSections(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);`
```

Думаю, ошибка в самом запросе, так как первый запрос все ищет правильно, находит максимальный индекс в таблице, а вот как его дальше передать - не знаю.

Comment: Скорее всего еще `exec` перед передачей в модель делать не надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл [QSqlQuery::prepare](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#prepare) именно в том, чтобы подготовить строку-запрос с отсутствующими параметрами для последующей подстановки.

```
qry->prepare("SELECT * FROM Missiles WHERE Missiles_id = ?");
qry->addBindValue(missId);
qry->exec();
```

Или

```
qry->prepare("SELECT * FROM Missiles WHERE Missiles_id = :id");
qry->bindValue(":id", missId);
qry->exec();
```

P.S:

Если подстановка не нужна, то `prepare` не нужно использовать вообще. Таким образом, ваш код

```
QSqlQuery qry1;
qry1.prepare("select max(Missiles_id) from Missiles");
qry1.exec();
```

превращается в

```
QSqlQuery qry1("select max(Missiles_id) from Missiles");
// если передана непустая строка, exec вызывается автоматически
```

И еще, если вам надо передать результат одного запроса в следующий (не говоря уже о том, что все это можно превратить в один запрос средствами `sql`), делать приведение типа `QVariant -> int` не нужно. `addBindValue` и `bindValue` ожидают именно `QVariant`.

Answer (score 2):

Что у вас тут?

```
"SELECT * FROM Missiles WHERE Missiles_id="+missId
```

Строка `char*` плюс целое число. Т.е. строка со сдвигом :) - например, если `missId` равно 5, то это получается указатель на строку

```
"T * FROM Missiles WHERE Missiles_id="
```

Если уж передаете строку - то сначала сделайте верную строку. Вариантов масса. Не скажу, что именно хорошего есть в Qt, не знаю...

Например, вариант с буфером:

```
char query[150];
sprintf(query,"SELECT * FROM Missiles WHERE Missiles_id=%d",missId);
qry->prepare(query);
```

Вариант со строкой С++:

```
qry->prepare((string("SELECT * FROM Missiles WHERE Missiles_id=")+to_string(missId)).c_str());
```

Вобщем, главное - правильно приготовьте строку запроса.

Comment: А у вас в примере с `sprintf` buffer overflow

Comment: @int3 Ну изменим 50 на 150 :) - это же только идея, как работать, в чем проблема, а не готовое решение...